# How to Allowed Options for BaseFieldDefinition on Custom Entity

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to access the allowed options on a custom entity's field that I created. (see code below) Is there a way to access this?

One field I would like to access, for example, is...
`$fields['category'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')`

Is there a way to get this information without loading a particular entity instance?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\customers\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityPublishedTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;

/**
 * Defines the Customer entity.
 *
 * @ingroup customers
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "customer_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("Customer"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\customers\CustomerEntityListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\customers\Entity\CustomerEntityViewsData",
 *
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\customers\Form\CustomerEntityForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\customers\Form\CustomerEntityForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\customers\Form\CustomerEntityForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\customers\Form\CustomerEntityDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\customers\CustomerEntityHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *     "access" = "Drupal\customers\CustomerEntityAccessControlHandler",
 *   },
 *   base_table = "customer_entity",
 *   translatable = FALSE,
 *   admin_permission = "administer customer entities",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "name",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "uid" = "user_id",
 *     "langcode" = "langcode",
 *     "published" = "status",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/content/customer_entity/{customer_entity}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/content/customer_entity/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/content/customer_entity/{customer_entity}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/content/customer_entity/{customer_entity}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/content/customer_entity",
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "customer_entity.settings"
 * )
 */
class CustomerEntity extends ContentEntityBase implements CustomerEntityInterface {

  use EntityChangedTrait;
  use EntityPublishedTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function preCreate(EntityStorageInterface $storage_controller, array &$values) {
    parent::preCreate($storage_controller, $values);
    $values += [
      'user_id' => \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getName() {
    return $this->get('name')->value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setName($name) {
    $this->set('name', $name);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCreatedTime() {
    return $this->get('created')->value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setCreatedTime($timestamp) {
    $this->set('created', $timestamp);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getOwner() {
    return $this->get('user_id')->entity;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getOwnerId() {
    return $this->get('user_id')->target_id;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setOwnerId($uid) {
    $this->set('user_id', $uid);
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setOwner(UserInterface $account) {
    $this->set('user_id', $account->id());
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

    // Add the published field.
    $fields += static::publishedBaseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

    $fields['user_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Authored by'))
      ->setDescription(t('The user ID of author of the Customer entity.'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'user')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'author',
        'weight' => 0,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'weight' => 5,
        'settings' => [
          'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
          'size' => '60',
          'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
          'placeholder' => '',
        ],
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    $fields['name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Name'))
      ->setSettings([
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setRequired(TRUE);

    $fields['email'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('email')
      ->setLabel(t('Email'))
      ->setSettings([
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setRequired(TRUE);

    $fields['phone'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Phone'))
      ->setSettings([
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setRequired(TRUE);

    $fields['state'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
      ->setSettings([
        'allowed_values' => [
          'AL' => 'Alabama',
          'AK' => 'Alaska',
          'AZ' => 'Arizona',
          'AR' => 'Arkansas',
          'CA' => 'California',
          'CO' => 'Colorado',
          'CT' => 'Connecticut',
          'DE' => 'Delaware',
          'DC' => 'District of Columbia',
          'FL' => 'Florida',
          'GA' => 'Georgia',
          'HI' => 'Hawaii',
          'ID' => 'Idaho',
          'IL' => 'Illinois',
          'IN' => 'Indiana',
          'IA' => 'Iowa',
          'KS' => 'Kansas',
          'KY' => 'Kentucky',
          'LA' => 'Louisiana',
          'ME' => 'Maine',
          'MD' => 'Maryland',
          'MA' => 'Massachusetts',
          'MI' => 'Michigan',
          'MN' => 'Minnesota',
          'MS' => 'Mississippi',
          'MO' => 'Missouri',
          'MT' => 'Montana',
          'NE' => 'Nebraska',
          'NV' => 'Nevada',
          'NH' => 'New Hampshire',
          'NJ' => 'New Jersey',
          'NM' => 'New Mexico',
          'NY' => 'New York',
          'NC' => 'North Carolina',
          'ND' => 'North Dakota',
          'OH' => 'Ohio',
          'OK' => 'Oklahoma',
          'OR' => 'Oregon',
          'PA' => 'Pennsylvania',
          'RI' => 'Rhode Island',
          'SC' => 'South Carolina',
          'SD' => 'South Dakota',
          'TN' => 'Tennessee',
          'TX' => 'Texas',
          'UT' => 'Utah',
          'VT' => 'Vermont',
          'VA' => 'Virginia',
          'WA' => 'Washington',
          'WV' => 'West Virginia',
          'WI' => 'Wisconsin',
          'WY' => 'Wyoming',
        ]
      ])
      ->setLabel('State')
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setCardinality(-1)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'options_buttons',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['territory'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Territory'))
      ->setDescription(t('If applicable, which part of the state does this customer serve?<br/>(e.g., North Louisiana, Middle and E Tennessee, Mississippi - South, etc.)'))
      ->setSettings([
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setRequired(FALSE);

    $fields['category'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
      ->setSettings([
        'allowed_values' => [
          'stairtreads_risers' => 'Stairtreads & Risers',
          'exterior_door_sills_frames' => 'Exterior Door Sills & Frames',
        ]
      ])
      ->setLabel(t('Product Category'))
      ->setSettings([
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setCardinality(-1)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'options_buttons',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['type'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
      ->setSettings([
        'allowed_values' => [
          'homeowner' => 'I am a Homeowner',
          'contractor' => 'I am a Contractor',
          'retail_dealer' => 'I am a Retail Dealer',
          'distributor' => 'I am a Distributor',
        ]
      ])
      ->setLabel(t('Customer Type'))
      ->setSettings([
        'max_length' => 50,
        'text_processing' => 0,
      ])
      ->setDefaultValue('')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -4,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setCardinality(-1)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'options_buttons',
        'weight' => -4,
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);

    $fields['status']->setDescription(t('A boolean indicating whether the Customer is published.'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'boolean_checkbox',
        'weight' => 51,
      ]);

    $fields['created'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
      ->setLabel(t('Created'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was created.'));

    $fields['changed'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('changed')
      ->setLabel(t('Changed'))
      ->setDescription(t('The time that the entity was last edited.'));

    return $fields;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$allowed_states = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')
   ->getBaseFieldDefinitions('customer_entity')['state']
   ->getSetting('allowed_values');
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down voted?! This was exactly what I needed. After getting the base field definition, i didn't know how to get to the allowed values setting. This got me there.

Comment: I edited it after initially posting to use the `\Drupal::service()` method shown by 4k4, as it was better than I originally had. I think I got the downvotes from my initial answer.

Answer (score 2):

Base fields can be added or modified by hooks. To get the active base field definitions use [EntityFieldManager::getBaseFieldDefinitions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetBaseFieldDefinitions/8.8.x):

```
$base_fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getBaseFieldDefinitions('customer_entity');
```

Comment: This helped me get the definition, but didn't quite get me to the allowed_values.